# How to Call this API (an ASP.NET WebAPI action)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How to call the API which I will mention below? How to assign a value to `requestMessage` inside the argument?

```
    [Route("api/studies")]
    public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> GetStudies(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
    {
        var query = QueryParser.Parse(requestMessage.RequestUri);
        var response = _studyQuery.Execute(query);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: API ≠ WebAPI. API means "application programming interface and is a term much much older and more widespread in use than just for Web-based services.

Answer (score 1):

With your information we only can know that you need to put your request in a HttpRequestMessage object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) using this constructor

```
public HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod method, string requestUri);
```

or this one

```
 public HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod method, Uri requestUri);
```

so your code should be like this:

```
HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage(method, requestUri);
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> response = GetStudies(httpRequestMessage);
```

Can you give us more info about the API or something to know what kind of request you have to do?

Comment: Thanks . this is the web API I need to call it using any Rest client